# Postgres Procedure Returns Table

Tags: postgresql, query

We have a table structure returned by this function:

```
RETURNS TABLE (ticker VARCHAR,
           current_recommendation INTEGER,
           previous_approved_recommendation INTEGER,
           date_appended TEXT,
           suggested_recommendation INTEGER,
           date_suggested TEXT,
           suggested_by VARCHAR,
           approved_recommendation INTEGER,
           date_accepted TEXT,
           approved_by VARCHAR,
           recommendation_status INTEGER
           )
```

On certain conditions, rather than returning values, we want to return just the first & last values, and everything else is NULL.

```
v_select := 'SELECT ''' || p_ticker || ''',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,' || v_status;
```

But it is not working:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type text does not match expected type character varying in column 1.
```

Any help would be great.  We are all kind of new at Postgres, after migrating some thing from ORacle.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can solve it by using an explicit cast.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(tic text)
RETURNS TABLE (foo VARCHAR, bar int)
AS $$
DECLARE
  sql text;
BEGIN
  sql := 'SELECT ''' || tic || ''', NULL';
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT test('A');
```

> ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type DETAIL:
>   Returned type text does not match expected type character varying in
>   column 1.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test1(tic text)
RETURNS TABLE (foo VARCHAR, bar int)
AS $$
DECLARE
  sql text;
BEGIN
  sql := 'SELECT ''' || tic || '''::VARCHAR, NULL::int';
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT test1('A');
```

> ```
> | test1 |
> | :---- |
> | (A,)  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=01edbb10426629135258adc4682d2470)*

Answer (score 0):

The part of your code that returns values is missing in the question, so let's assume that it's `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_select`.

### Why it errors out

The most likely explanation for *Returned type text does not match expected type character varying in column 1* is that `p_ticker` is of type `text`, not `varchar`. Even though in practice there is no difference between unconstrained varchar and text, they are not the same type. Quote from the [plpgsql manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING):

> But to return a composite (row) value, you must write an expression
>   delivering exactly the requested column set. This may require use of
>   explicit casting.

### Simpler method without SELECT

Returning values for a SETOF TABLE doesn't necessarily require a query.
The column identifiers that are inside the `TABLE(...)` declaration are **available as variables** for the purpose of being assigned. Assuming that the rest of the code does not affect these variables already, you could simply write:

```
ticker := p_ticker;
recommendation_status := v_status;
-- other output columns are NULL by default
RETURN NEXT;
```

Doc quote:

> When a PL/pgSQL function is declared to return SETOF sometype, the
>   procedure to follow is slightly different. In that case, the
>   individual items to return are specified by a sequence of RETURN NEXT
>   or RETURN QUERY commands, and then a final RETURN command with no
>   argument is used to indicate that the function has finished executing

(and RETURNS TABLE (...) is equivalent to RETURNS SETOF compositeType in that context).

### Simpler method with SELECT

Even if the SELECT was needed, it doesn't need to be built as dynamic SQL into a string. Better let the plpgsql language handle the mix of variables by writing the query direcly:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT p_ticker::varchar, NULL, NULL, ..., v_status;
```

That's more efficient and saves the trouble to quote the literals, which the sample code in the question forgets to do (with the `v_select` of the question, if `p_ticker` contained a single quote, the resulting statement would be incorrect).

Comment: This is very awesome.  In many ways, must more straightforward that what Oracle offers.....thank you!!!